# Passing data to fragment or page after Login successful

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

I am working on a spring web MVC project with Thymeleaf integrated for presentation layer. I need to pass data to a fragment on the page displayed after log in successful which I am redirected according to spring security configuration.

Has anyone found a way to pass data to a page right after log in successful or to a fragment from the controller?

Answer (score 0):

So essentially wha i have done is create a /succes_login that gets called and then renders fragment as per here: http://www.thymeleaf.org/whatsnew21.html#spfrag

Hope that helps, let me know and i'll investigate further.